# refer to variables when creating XML nodes in as3(air)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

Im trying to refer to a vaiable in my XML obejct

```
var newElements:XML = new XML();
newElements = <data></data>;

var myNode= "cell0";
newElements.myNode.image = node_image[0];

every works fine:
newElements.cell0.image = node_image[0];

how do i refer the variable myNode as a new node(cell0)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following syntax:

```
var myNode= "cell0";
newElements[myNode].image = node_image[0];
```